# GPIO programming on Gigabyte motherboards

Tags: x86, reverse-engineering, gpio

I have IMB310TN motherboard with 8 GPIO pins. I'd like to use them, but there is no documentation about it. Gigabyte support responded, that documentation is confidential :).
As I see, similar GPIO pins exists on various Gigabyte motherboards, so probably they should work simillary. I suspect that GPIO pins are connected to I2C bus, so I tried to identify i2c devices, but without success:

```
i2cdetect -l
i2c-3   i2c         i915 gmbus misc                     I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c         i915 gmbus dpb                      I2C adapter
i2c-6   i2c         DPDDC-C                             I2C adapter
i2c-4   i2c         i915 gmbus dpd                      I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c         i915 gmbus dpc                      I2C adapter
i2c-0   smbus       SMBus I801 adapter at efa0          SMBus adapter
i2c-7   i2c         DPDDC-D                             I2C adapter
i2c-5   i2c         DPDDC-B                             I2C adapter
```

The only bus where something is detected is 7:

```
i2cdetect -y 7
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: 40 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea what to do next. Did someone succeeded to use GPIO on some Gigabyte motherboard ?

Comment: How do you know about those GPIO lines? What is the Linux distribution you have? And what _lsmod_ shows on the most recent kernel version you are able to install?

Comment: According to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets there are plenty possible chipsets on this type of motherboard, so you must provide exact chipset and SoC model you are using. And see above comment, there will be necessary information as well.